# discord export buttton array

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

in my /report command, a channel is created, into which the button and embed are sent. I need to store the id of the new channel the button was sent to in order to interact with that channel later on. I tried to create an array and use exports to export it to my InteractionCreater file in which I have written: const reportArr = require('../commands/Report/report')

```
module.exports = { 

name: 'interactionCreate', 

async execute(interaction,client) { 

if(interaction.isCommand()){ 

// if (!interaction.isCommand()) return; 

const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName); 

if (!command) return; 

try { 

await command.execute(interaction,client); 

} catch (error) { 

console.error(error); 

await interaction.reply({content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral: true}); 

} 

} 

else if(interaction.isButton()){ 

if(interaction.customId.includes('acceptB')){ 

console.log(reportArr.reports) 

} 

}
```

but in InteractionCreater i get undefeated even though if i try to output the array in command then they are output. Tell me how can I put my channel in the InteractionCreater file, which is created when the /report command is sent. This is what sending embed\button looks like:

```
(Creating new channel).then(async reportChannel => {const acceptButton = new MessageActionRow()
    .addComponents(
        new MessageButton()
            .setCustomId(`acceptB`)
            .setLabel('Accept')
            .setStyle('SUCCESS')
            .setEmoji('✅')
    );
await client.channels.cache.get(`${settings["tickets-log"]}`).send({
    content: `<@&${settings.moder}>`
}).then(idmessage => {
    idmessage.delete()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a channel and then send a message and button into it:

```js
const channelName = `Channel Name Here` // Change this
const channel = await interaction.guild.channels.create(channelName, {
    parent: 'parentID', // Change this
    type: 'GUILD_TEXT',
    permissionOverwrites: [{ // For if you want it private, otherwise delete this whole section from here
        id: interaction.guild.id,
        deny: [
            'VIEW_CHANNEL'
        ]
    }, {
        id: interaction.user.id, // id of person who started the channel creation process
        allow: [
            'SEND_MESSAGES', 'VIEW_CHANNEL', 'EMBED_LINKS', 'ATTACH_FILES', 'READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY'
        ]
    }, {
        id: 'adminRoleID', // Change this
        allow: [
            'SEND_MESSAGES', 'VIEW_CHANNEL', 'EMBED_LINKS', 'ATTACH_FILES', 'READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY'
        ]
    }, {
        id: 'anyAdditionalRoleID', // Change this
        allow: [
            'SEND_MESSAGES', 'VIEW_CHANNEL', 'EMBED_LINKS', 'ATTACH_FILES', 'READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY'
        ]
    }] // For if you want it private, otherwise delete this whole section up to here
})

const acceptButton = new MessageActionRow()
    .addComponents(
        new MessageButton()
        .setCustomId(`acceptB`)
        .setLabel('Accept')
        .setStyle('SUCCESS')
        .setEmoji('✅')
    )
await channel.send({
    content: `<@&${settings.moder}>`,
    components: [acceptButton]
})
```

Then to make that button do something:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'interactionCreate',
    async execute(interaction, client) {
        if (interaction.isCommand()) {
            const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);
            if (!command) return;
            try {
                await command.execute(interaction, client);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
                await interaction.reply({
                    content: 'There was an error while executing this command!',
                    ephemeral: true
                });
            }
        } else if (interaction.isButton()) {
            if (interaction.customId === 'acceptB') {
                console.log('button clicked') // Do what you want to do here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I describe the button event in the command file?

Comment: The actual clicking of the button event doesn't go into the command file. Only the sending of the button, The button goes under the interactionCreate listener shown in second code block